# あたり at the end of a clause

Tags: meaning, nuances

Dear fellow lovers of the Japanese language,
please bear with my possibly foolish question.

I've come across this sentence in a visual novel (Fate/Stay Night): が、人の噂など当てにならないのが常だ。こんな勝負を持ち出すあたり、男嫌いというより、単に今まで興味がなかっただけかもしれない。

I'm not sure as to what exactly "あたり" means in this context. Is it the usual meaning as a noun (success / vicinity), or something else? Can it be replaced with something like のは without the sentence losing much of its original meaning?

Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @virmaior This is not 当たり but 辺り which doesn't usually conjugate.

Comment: That is not "at the end of a sentence".  It is right in the middle of it.

Comment: That あたり is "circumstances".

Answer (score 10):

> "Is it the usual meaning as a noun (success / vicinity), or something else?"

You are thinking of another word 「[当]{あ}たり」 as you mention "success".  "Vicinity", however, is strongly related to the word in question.

This one is 「[辺]{あた}り」.  「当たり」 and 「辺り」 are pronounced differently as well -- pitch accent-wise, that is.

This usage of 「～～～あたり」(It is more than O.K. to write it in kana.) may not be easy for the learner.  It is a somewhat ***euphemistic*** way of giving an example and making a comment about it.

The structure is **「(an example) + あたり + (speaker's comment or opinion)」**.

> "Can it be replaced with something like のは without the sentence losing much of its original meaning?"

Good insight!  That is exactly what I meant by "euphemistic".

If you said something like "～～が～～するのは～～だ", it could at times sound too straightforward and/or judgemental.  By using 「あたり」, you can *soften* things a little without changing the meaning.

「こんな勝負を持ち出すあたり、～～～」 means:

"Her proposing a match like that, for instance, (makes me wonder ~~~~)"

Comment: It might be easier to comprehend when you add "こんな勝負を持ち出す辺り（からみて/からいえば）", etc.