# How to interpret あたり in this sentence?

Tags: expressions

From [this link](https://qiita.com/maskedw/items/e73df32007934e75d9e3),

> ずらずらとでてくるので、無関係そうな所は除外しています。`ignoring nonexistent directory "/dammy/xxx"` という**あたり**がそれっぽいですね

There is [another question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21774/%E3%81%82%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8A-at-the-end-of-the-sentence), where あたり is used in the following way:

> 「(an example) + あたり + (speaker's comment or opinion)」

which, as the answer indicates, is used to soften the tone. With this interpretation, my understanding of this sentence would be something like:

> Since the code is quite an endless stream, I am excluding bits that are not related. Lines containing `ignoring nonexistent directory "/dammy/xxx"` seem to be aplenty and I've removed a lot of them.

Just doesn't seem right to me though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This あたり refers to a location **around** something. The question you linked is using あたり in a more abstract sense, but in your case, it simply refers to a physical location on screen. The author is saying "The place **around** the lines that say `ignoring nonexistent directory "/dammy/xxx"` seems relevant".

Since this is an output from a program, he used という, but this ～というあたり can be safely replaced by simpler ～のあたり.

See also: [Difference between 辺り and 周り](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/57266/5010)