# Understanding あたりも

Tags: grammar

From 義妹生活 ch3, protagonist was describing 目玉焼き cooked for him by his stepsister,

> あくまでも基本に忠実、変なアレンジをすることもなく、きっちりと教科書通りのものを作ったんだろう。黄身や全体の形が崩れたりもせず、きれいな円を描くそれは、味も食感も見た目通りの完成度だ。過度なメシマズ属性を持っていない**あたりも**、二次元世界の架空の妹と違って、平淡でドライな義妹である。

I'm not sure about the あたりも part. Can I replace it with なども? Or あたりから見ても? What も might be doing here?

Also, the subject for 持っていない is 目玉焼き?

Comment: Duplicate? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/76370/45489

Comment: This should be closer: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21774/5010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the answer naruto linked, あたり is a way of making thing indirect. And も works the same way here.

Possible variants:

1. メシマズ属性を持っていない**あたり**, 二次元世界の...
2. メシマズ属性を持っていない**のも**, 二次元世界の
3. メシマズ属性を持っていない｛**ところ、点**｝**なども**, 二次元世界の

あたりからみても would be fine (but sounds lengthy). なども requires a nominalizer as above.  Comparison: 持っていない**のが** would be *exactly not having メシマズ property makes the sister different from fiction*.

There could be many properties a fictional sister could have other than メシマズ: ツンデレ, ドジっ子 etc. Both あたり and も imply the sister doesn't have メシマズ property, nor  other common-for-fictional-sister properties like ツンデレ.

The subject of 持ってない is the sister.